# Data from array only exists for current bar. How can I reference historical values?

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

The script prints 2 labels on the current bar. These labels are the bullish and bearish probabilities of breaking a key level. I have split these strings to pull out just the percentage string value and converted to float values so that rules can be created with them. These floats are stored in their respective variables "bull_prob" and "bear_prob".

The problem is these variables only have data on the current bar and zero values on historical bars. I created 2 new arrays bull_hist[] and bear_hist[] and push the current bar value to them so that they can be referenced historically.  When I check the array size I can see that it has pushed values for all historical bars. However they are still all zero values except for the last index.

For testing I have created basic indicator rules that simply indicate buy on a bull candle and sell on a bear candle, but also considers if the probability rule is true.

Current result: Indicator works correctly for the current bar only. This means that while live or during replay the rules are processed appropriately. However you cannot see any past indicators unless you replay. This also means if I convert this to a strategy it would find zero trades.

Intended result: bull_prob and bear_prob should show the probability value that existed on that bar as seen in the data window. I'm currently plotting their output to data window. Previous indicators should be visible on the chart.

Full Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Probability Analyzer", overlay = true)

import HeWhoMustNotBeNamed/Logger/2 as log
var logger = log.Logger.new(minimumLevel='Trace', textSize = size.normal)
logger.init()

// Tooltips 
string t1 = "Set the pivot period"
string t2 = "Set the response period. A low value returns a short-term structure and a high value returns a long-term structure.
  If you disable this option the pivot length above will be used."


// Inputs
int pa_len = input.int(defval = 20
     , title = "Structure Period"
     , minval = 1
     , tooltip = t1)

int pa_res = input.int(defval = 7
     , title = "Structure Response"
     , minval = 1
     , tooltip = t2)


n        = bar_index 
var pup  = float(na)
var pdn  = float(na)
var piup = int(na)
var pidn = int(na)

// Matrix & Array 
var vals          = matrix.new<float>(9, 4, 0.0)
var string [] txt = array.new<string>(2, "")


// Functions 

Current(v)=>
    str = ""
    val1 = float(na)
    val2 = float(na)

    if v >= 0
        if v == 1
            str  := "SMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 0, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 0, 3) 
        else if v == 2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 1, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 1, 3) 
        else if v > 2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 2, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 2, 3) 
    else if v <= 0
        if v == -1
            str  := "SMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 3, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 3, 3) 
        else if v == -2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 4, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 4, 3) 
        else if v < -2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 5, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 5, 3)
    
    [str, val1, val2]


// ~~ Pivots {
pup     := math.max(pup[1], high)
pdn     := math.min(pdn[1], low)
pa_high  = ta.pivothigh(high, pa_len, pa_len)
pa_low   = ta.pivotlow(low, pa_len, pa_len)

if pa_high
    pup := pa_high
else if pa_low
    pdn := pa_low


// Structure
var pos = 0

if pup > pup[1]
    piup := n
    centerBull = math.round(math.avg(piup[1] ,n))
    if pos <= 0
        pos := 1
        matrix.set(vals, 6, 0, matrix.get(vals, 6, 0) + 1)
    else if pos == 1 and pup > pup[1] and pup[1] == pup[pa_res]
        pos := 2
        matrix.set(vals, 6, 1,matrix.get(vals ,6 ,1) + 1)
    else if pos > 1 and pup > pup[1] and pup[1] == pup[pa_res]
        pos := pos + 1
        matrix.set(vals ,6 ,2,matrix.get(vals, 6, 2) + 1)

else if pup < pup[1]
    piup := n - pa_len

if pdn < pdn[1]
    pidn := n
    centerBear = math.round(math.avg(pidn[1], n))
    if pos >= 0
        pos := -1
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 0, matrix.get(vals, 7, 0) + 1)
    else if pos == -1 and pdn < pdn[1] and pdn[1] == pdn[pa_res]
        pos := -2
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 1, matrix.get(vals, 7, 1) + 1)
    else if pos < -1 and pdn < pdn[1] and pdn[1] == pdn[pa_res]
        pos := pos - 1
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 2, matrix.get(vals, 7, 2) + 1)
else if pdn > pdn[1]
    pidn := n - pa_len

var float[] bull_hist_txt = array.new_float()
var float[] bear_hist_txt = array.new_float()

// Probability Calculation
if ta.change(pos)
    if pos > 0 and pos[1] > 0 or pos < 0 and pos[1] < 0
        if  matrix.get(vals, 8, 0) < matrix.get(vals, 8, 1)
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 2, matrix.get(vals, 8, 2) + 1)
        else
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 3, matrix.get(vals, 8, 3) + 1)
    else
        if  matrix.get(vals, 8, 0) > matrix.get(vals, 8, 1)
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 2, matrix.get(vals, 8, 2) + 1)
        else
            matrix.set(vals,8, 3, matrix.get(vals, 8, 3) + 1)

    //Score Calulation
    float buC0 = matrix.get(vals, 0, 0), float buC1 = matrix.get(vals, 0, 2)
    float buS0 = matrix.get(vals, 1, 0), float buS1 = matrix.get(vals, 1, 2)
    float buB0 = matrix.get(vals, 2, 0), float buB1 = matrix.get(vals, 2, 2)
    float beC0 = matrix.get(vals, 3, 0), float beC1 = matrix.get(vals, 3, 2)
    float beS0 = matrix.get(vals, 4, 0), float beS1 = matrix.get(vals, 4, 2)
    float beB0 = matrix.get(vals, 5, 0), float beB1 = matrix.get(vals, 5, 2)
    float tbuC = matrix.get(vals, 6, 0), float tbuS = matrix.get(vals, 6, 1)
    float tbuB = matrix.get(vals, 6, 2), float tbeC = matrix.get(vals, 7, 0)
    float tbeS = matrix.get(vals, 7, 1), float tbeB = matrix.get(vals, 7, 2)


    // Bull
    if (pos[1] == 1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 0, buC0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 1, math.round(((buC0 + 1) / tbuC) * 100, 2))
    
    if (pos[1] == 1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos == 2
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 2, buC1 +1 )
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 3, math.round(((buC1 + 1) / tbuC) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == 2 and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 0, buS0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 1, math.round(((buS0 +1 ) / tbuS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == 2 and pos > 2
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 2, buS1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 3, math.round(((buS1 + 1) / tbuS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] > 2 and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 0, buB0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 1, math.round(((buB0 + 1) / tbuB) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] > 2 and pos > pos[1]
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 2, buB1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 3, math.round(((buB1 + 1) / tbuB) * 100, 2))
    
    // Bear
    if (pos[1] == -1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 0, beC0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 1, math.round(((beC0 + 1) / tbeC) * 100, 2))
    
    if (pos[1] == -1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos == -2
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 2, beC1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 3, math.round(((beC1 + 1) / tbeC) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == -2 and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 0, beS0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 1, math.round(((beS0 + 1) / tbeS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == -2 and pos < -2
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 2, beS1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 3, math.round(((beS1 + 1) / tbeS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] < -2 and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 0, beB0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 1, math.round(((beB0 + 1) / tbeB) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] < -2 and pos < pos[1]
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 2, beB1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 3, math.round(((beB1 + 1) / tbeB) * 100, 2))
    
    [str, val1, val2] = Current(pos)
    
    array.set(txt, 0, "CHoCH: " + str.tostring(val1, format.percent))
    array.set(txt, 1, str + str.tostring(val2, format.percent))
    matrix.set(vals, 8, 0, val1)
    matrix.set(vals, 8, 1, val2)


// Probability 
var prob1 = label.new(na, na, na
     , color = color(na)
     , textcolor = chart.fg_color
     , style = label.style_label_left)

var prob2 = label.new(na, na, na
     , color = color(na)
     , textcolor = chart.fg_color
     , style = label.style_label_left)


var float bull_prob = 0.0
var float bear_prob = 0.0
var float[] bull_hist = array.new_float()
var float[] bear_hist = array.new_float()


if barstate.islast
    str1 = pos < 0 ? array.get(txt, 0) : array.get(txt, 1)
    label.set_xy(prob1, n, pup)
    label.set_text(prob1, str1)

    str2 = pos > 0 ? array.get(txt, 0) : array.get(txt, 1)
    label.set_xy(prob2, n, pdn)
    label.set_text(prob2, str2)
 
    // Split the strings to pull out percentage and convert to integer
    str1_split1  = str.split(str1, ':')
    str1_split2  = str.split(array.get(str1_split1, 1), '%')
    bull_prob    := str.tonumber(array.get(str1_split2, 0))  // Need to access this value for all historical bars

    str2_split1  = str.split(str2, ':')
    str2_split2  = str.split(array.get(str2_split1, 1), '%')
    bear_prob    := str.tonumber(array.get(str2_split2, 0)) // Need to access this value for all historical bars

array.push(bull_hist, bull_prob)
array.push(bear_hist, bear_prob)

bull_prob_up = bull_prob > bear_prob
bear_prob_dn = bear_prob > bull_prob

plotchar(bull_prob, 'Bull Prob', color=color.new(#ffffff, 100))
plotchar(bear_prob, 'Bear Prob', color=color.new(#ffffff, 100))

plotshape(close > open and bull_prob_up
   , title = 'Type 1 - Buy'
   , style = shape.triangleup
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.belowbar
   , color = color.green) 

plotshape(close < open and bear_prob_dn
   , title = 'Type 1 - Sell'
   , style = shape.triangledown
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.abovebar
   , color = color.green)
```

I have tried more things than I can count or remember. I an not set on any particular method. Any way that can produce the intended result is fine by me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Probability Analyzer", overlay = true)

import HeWhoMustNotBeNamed/Logger/2 as log
var logger = log.Logger.new(minimumLevel='Trace', textSize = size.normal)
logger.init()

// Tooltips 
string t1 = "Set the pivot period"
string t2 = "Set the response period. A low value returns a short-term structure and a high value returns a long-term structure.
  If you disable this option the pivot length above will be used."


// Inputs
int pa_len = input.int(defval = 20
     , title = "Structure Period"
     , minval = 1
     , tooltip = t1)

int pa_res = input.int(defval = 7
     , title = "Structure Response"
     , minval = 1
     , tooltip = t2)


n        = bar_index 
var pup  = float(na)
var pdn  = float(na)
var piup = int(na)
var pidn = int(na)

// Matrix & Array 
var vals          = matrix.new<float>(9, 4, 0.0)
var string [] txt = array.new<string>(2, "")


// Functions 

Current(v)=>
    str = ""
    val1 = float(na)
    val2 = float(na)

    if v >= 0
        if v == 1
            str  := "SMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 0, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 0, 3) 
        else if v == 2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 1, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 1, 3) 
        else if v > 2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 2, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 2, 3) 
    else if v <= 0
        if v == -1
            str  := "SMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 3, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 3, 3) 
        else if v == -2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 4, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 4, 3) 
        else if v < -2
            str  := "BMS: "
            val1 := matrix.get(vals, 5, 1)
            val2 := matrix.get(vals, 5, 3)
    
    [str, val1, val2]


// ~~ Pivots {
pup     := math.max(pup[1], high)
pdn     := math.min(pdn[1], low)
pa_high  = ta.pivothigh(high, pa_len, pa_len)
pa_low   = ta.pivotlow(low, pa_len, pa_len)

if pa_high
    pup := pa_high
else if pa_low
    pdn := pa_low


// Structure
var pos = 0

if pup > pup[1]
    piup := n
    centerBull = math.round(math.avg(piup[1] ,n))
    if pos <= 0
        pos := 1
        matrix.set(vals, 6, 0, matrix.get(vals, 6, 0) + 1)
    else if pos == 1 and pup > pup[1] and pup[1] == pup[pa_res]
        pos := 2
        matrix.set(vals, 6, 1,matrix.get(vals ,6 ,1) + 1)
    else if pos > 1 and pup > pup[1] and pup[1] == pup[pa_res]
        pos := pos + 1
        matrix.set(vals ,6 ,2,matrix.get(vals, 6, 2) + 1)

else if pup < pup[1]
    piup := n - pa_len

if pdn < pdn[1]
    pidn := n
    centerBear = math.round(math.avg(pidn[1], n))
    if pos >= 0
        pos := -1
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 0, matrix.get(vals, 7, 0) + 1)
    else if pos == -1 and pdn < pdn[1] and pdn[1] == pdn[pa_res]
        pos := -2
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 1, matrix.get(vals, 7, 1) + 1)
    else if pos < -1 and pdn < pdn[1] and pdn[1] == pdn[pa_res]
        pos := pos - 1
        matrix.set(vals, 7, 2, matrix.get(vals, 7, 2) + 1)
else if pdn > pdn[1]
    pidn := n - pa_len

var float[] val1_hist = array.new_float(n+1)
var float[] val2_hist = array.new_float(n+1)

// Probability Calculation
if ta.change(pos)
    if pos > 0 and pos[1] > 0 or pos < 0 and pos[1] < 0
        if  matrix.get(vals, 8, 0) < matrix.get(vals, 8, 1)
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 2, matrix.get(vals, 8, 2) + 1)
        else
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 3, matrix.get(vals, 8, 3) + 1)
    else
        if  matrix.get(vals, 8, 0) > matrix.get(vals, 8, 1)
            matrix.set(vals, 8, 2, matrix.get(vals, 8, 2) + 1)
        else
            matrix.set(vals,8, 3, matrix.get(vals, 8, 3) + 1)

    //Score Calulation
    float buC0 = matrix.get(vals, 0, 0), float buC1 = matrix.get(vals, 0, 2)
    float buS0 = matrix.get(vals, 1, 0), float buS1 = matrix.get(vals, 1, 2)
    float buB0 = matrix.get(vals, 2, 0), float buB1 = matrix.get(vals, 2, 2)
    float beC0 = matrix.get(vals, 3, 0), float beC1 = matrix.get(vals, 3, 2)
    float beS0 = matrix.get(vals, 4, 0), float beS1 = matrix.get(vals, 4, 2)
    float beB0 = matrix.get(vals, 5, 0), float beB1 = matrix.get(vals, 5, 2)
    float tbuC = matrix.get(vals, 6, 0), float tbuS = matrix.get(vals, 6, 1)
    float tbuB = matrix.get(vals, 6, 2), float tbeC = matrix.get(vals, 7, 0)
    float tbeS = matrix.get(vals, 7, 1), float tbeB = matrix.get(vals, 7, 2)


    // Bull
    if (pos[1] == 1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 0, buC0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 1, math.round(((buC0 + 1) / tbuC) * 100, 2))
    
    if (pos[1] == 1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos == 2
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 2, buC1 +1 )
        matrix.set(vals, 0, 3, math.round(((buC1 + 1) / tbuC) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == 2 and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 0, buS0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 1, math.round(((buS0 +1 ) / tbuS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == 2 and pos > 2
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 2, buS1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 1, 3, math.round(((buS1 + 1) / tbuS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] > 2 and pos < 0
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 0, buB0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 1, math.round(((buB0 + 1) / tbuB) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] > 2 and pos > pos[1]
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 2, buB1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 2, 3, math.round(((buB1 + 1) / tbuB) * 100, 2))
    
    // Bear
    if (pos[1] == -1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 0, beC0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 1, math.round(((beC0 + 1) / tbeC) * 100, 2))
    
    if (pos[1] == -1 or pos[1] == 0) and pos == -2
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 2, beC1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 3, 3, math.round(((beC1 + 1) / tbeC) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == -2 and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 0, beS0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 1, math.round(((beS0 + 1) / tbeS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] == -2 and pos < -2
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 2, beS1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 4, 3, math.round(((beS1 + 1) / tbeS) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] < -2 and pos > 0
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 0, beB0 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 1, math.round(((beB0 + 1) / tbeB) * 100, 2))
    
    if pos[1] < -2 and pos < pos[1]
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 2, beB1 + 1)
        matrix.set(vals, 5, 3, math.round(((beB1 + 1) / tbeB) * 100, 2))
    
    [str, val1, val2] = Current(pos)

    array.set(txt, 0, "CHoCH: " + str.tostring(val1, format.percent))
    array.set(txt, 1, str + str.tostring(val2, format.percent))
    matrix.set(vals, 8, 0, val1)
    matrix.set(vals, 8, 1, val2)
    array.push(val1_hist, val1)
    array.push(val2_hist, val2)
    

logger.info(str.tostring(array.size(val1_hist)))

// Probability 
var prob1 = label.new(na, na, na
     , color = color(na)
     , textcolor = chart.fg_color
     , style = label.style_label_left)

var prob2 = label.new(na, na, na
     , color = color(na)
     , textcolor = chart.fg_color
     , style = label.style_label_left)


if barstate.islast
    str1 = pos < 0 ? array.get(txt, 0) : array.get(txt, 1)
    label.set_xy(prob1, n, pup)
    label.set_text(prob1, str1)

    str2 = pos > 0 ? array.get(txt, 0) : array.get(txt, 1)
    label.set_xy(prob2, n, pdn)
    label.set_text(prob2, str2)
 
int val1_size = array.size(val1_hist) -1
int val2_size = array.size(val2_hist) -1

float bear_val = pos > 0 ? array.get(val1_hist, val1_size) : array.get(val2_hist, val2_size)
float bull_val = pos < 0 ? array.get(val1_hist, val1_size) : array.get(val2_hist, val2_size)

bull_prob = bull_val > bear_val
bear_prob = bear_val > bull_val

plotshape(close > open and bull_prob
   , title = 'Type 1 - Buy'
   , style = shape.triangleup
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.belowbar
   , color = color.green) 

plotshape(close < open and bear_prob
   , title = 'Type 1 - Sell'
   , style = shape.triangledown
   , size = size.small
   , location = location.abovebar
   , color = color.green) 

plotchar(bull_val, 'Bull Prob', color=color.new(#ffffff, 100))
plotchar(bear_val, 'Bear Prob', color=color.new(#ffffff, 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loops and `array.get(id, index)` to get the historical values of the array.

Comment: Problem is all of the historical values in the array I'm saving them to are zeroes. Doesn't make sense. Index 0 has the expected value and the rest are 0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would suggest rewriting the program and the logic flow. If `array.last(id)` isn’t showing the intended result, then look into how the values are stored and retrieved.